# Isolated Current Shunt Amplifier

Tags: current, current-measurement, current-sensing, isolated

I have twenty isolated power supplies (around 40 V max) which need to have their current draw sensed and monitored. I'm currently using a TI INA138 current sense amplifier, which sort of works.

However the Load RTNs (S1/S2 RTN below) and the amplifiers power supply RTN (VS) need to be common to within less than 500 kOhms for the output to be accurate. Above this, the output voltage starts to rise.

Are there other current shunt amplifiers which will work with improved isolation? or is there a better way to approach this? In practice I have 20x isolated supplies.

[image]

Comment: What max current through RS?

Comment: have you figured out why they need to be commoned to get the correct reading?

Comment: Max current is around 3A. I'm really not sure why they need to be common. 500K isolation isn't bad, but I'm concious it might go down the more I parallel up these current sense circuits.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the AD8211. Here no coupling of the supply is needed.
It is able to reject a common mode DC voltage up to 65V without needing a coupling of the supply.

You should scale the shunt such that the output voltage is in a desired range.

Datasheet: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8211.pdf

The reason why the INA180 is not able to monitor your currents is that is has only a Common-mode range (VCM): –0.2 V to +26 V (see Datasheet)

[image: screenshot from the datasheet of the AD8211 https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8211.pdf]